# Find which region of the plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the following equation has a unique solution $y'=\tan(x+y), y(x_0)=y_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find which region of the plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the following equation has a unique solution $y'=\tan(x+y), y(x_0)=y_0$

**MY Attempt**

Let $t=x+y \implies  t'=1+y' \implies y'=t'-1$

Hence $t'-1=\tan t \implies t'=\tan t+1 $

By using varaible and separable

$\frac{dt}{\tan t+1}=dx$ is this right way?

Comment: For the answer to the question in the title, you just need to find out the domain of the right side and that the function is continuously differentiable there. // To continue the solution, use the half-angle parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value problem  $$y'=\tan(x+y), y(x_0)=y_0 $$ will have a unique solution on a region about the point $(x_0, y_0)$ if both $\tan (x+y)$ and $$\frac {\partial }{\partial y}\tan(x+y)$$ are continuous on that region.

You can take over from here.